# Find the name of TextBox inside a listbox control

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a list box (below) which has 2 TextBox in, the data from the database shows fine in the text box. However I want to be able to save the values up to the database, as initially the text boxes wouold be blank until the user enters their name in them.

As the text boxes are sat in listbox I think I got to do a find to find the name of the textbox to be able to access the Text="name" to save to the data base.

I tried with the visual tree helper but I couldnt get it to work. Is the visual tree helper the right way to go about it?

```
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,20,0,0" x:Name="lst_userProfiles" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stk_container">
                        <!-- FIRST NAME-->
                        <TextBlock Text="First Name: " FontSize="22" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding UP_firstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="400" x:Name="txt_firstName" />
                        <!-- LAST NAME -->
                        <TextBlock Text="Surname: " FontSize="22" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding UP_lastName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="400" x:Name="txt_surname" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

code behind

```
     private void btn_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //first name
        ListBoxItem _firstName = this.lst_userProfiles.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem("txt_firstName") as ListBoxItem;
        TextBox firstName = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<TextBox>(_firstName);
        string getFirstName = Convert.ToString(firstName);

        //lst name
        ListBoxItem _lasyName = this.lst_userProfiles.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem("txt_surname") as ListBoxItem;
        TextBox lastName = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<TextBox>(_lasyName);
        string getLastName = Convert.ToString(lastName);



        Service1Client svc = new Service1Client();
        svc.AddProfileCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(svc_AddProfileCompleted);
        svc.AddProfileAsync(loginID, getFirstName, getLastName);
    }

     private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

            if (child != null && child is T) {
                return (T)child;
            }
            else {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Taking a step back, if your goal is to get the value of the TextBox, iterating through the visual tree is not the correct approach. I believe you already have the answer in your question: Two way binding.  Just use the list bound to the view to save the data you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "Just use the list bound to the view to save the data you want" ?

Comment: Your text box is bound two way (see your code), which means when the text field is changed, it's going to automatically update the underlying data.  More Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852595.aspx

Comment: Yea Im not sure I need it to be TwoWay bound. I am updating the value through the service client. And I need to pass the TextBox.Text into the parameters of the service client.

Comment: This is the way I have tried but I get an errorhttp://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7Error An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: BrianV is right. You may want to bind the ListBox to an ObservableCollection. It makes everything easier for you.

Comment: Any chance of a code example

Comment: Try this: http://mobileosgeek.com/simple-use-of-observable-collection-in-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understood why you are doing it in this way but you can try this code.

```
        List<string> name = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach(ListPickerItem lpi in lst_userProfiles.Items )
        {
            foreach(TextBox tb in (lpi.Content as StackPanel).Children)
            {
                name[i++] = tb.Name;
            }
        }
```